# does any word have the meaning of "overwhelming" but in a positive nature?

Tags: vocabulary

I want to say I was a brand representative and attracted a surprisingly high volume of students' awareness by organising different activities. Below is my whole sentence.

> "As a brand representative of ABC Company, I have successfully raised the brand awareness of the firm with ***an unexpectedly overwhelming response from student*** through organising various of promotion activities "

I find that the bolded part seems a bit confusing. Could anyone please give me some suggestions on how should I improve this sentence?

Comment: 'resulting in an unexpected overwhelming response from students' or 'resulting in an overwhelming response from students (which was quite unexpected)'.

Comment: Overwhelming is not inherently negative. I would say that the sentence is more confusing thanks to the redundant "unexpectedly" than it is the "overwhelming".

Comment: There is nothing especially 'negative' about *overwhelming*. It becomes a trifle unwieldy when used with another long word like 'unexpectedly'. But I would put 'student' into the plural, and eliminate the 'of' after 'various'. The sentence would also benefit from a comma after 'students'. 'Promotion' needs to be 'promotional'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Thank you so much for your advice. If now I change my sentence to "As a brand representative of ABC Company, I organised various of promotion events and have successfully raised the brand awareness of the firm resulting in an unexpected overwhelming response from students.", does it look fine? Do I use the correct tense in the first line of my sentence?

Comment: I suggest: As a brand representative of the ABC Company, I organised various promotional events, and have successfully raised the brand awareness of the firm; resulting in an unexpected and overwhelming response from students'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on a false premise. [About 2,670 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22overwhelming+sense+of+joy%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) in Google Books for *overwhelming **sense of joy*** clearly indicate that the word is not inherently negative. Anything beyond that is just opinion-based "writing advice".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Indeed the urban coinage of the term *underwhelming* is clear evidence to the fact that *an overwhelming response* is actually quite a spiffing thing to have. (if you will forgive my uncommonly *Boris Johnsonian* language)

Comment: Also *overwhelmingly positive response* because of course it is.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A question being based on a false premise does not make it off-topic. Rather, it is answerable by explaining why the premise is false. I suggest that you post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about [astounding](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/astounding)?: (adjective)
capable of overwhelming with amazement; stunningly surprising.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, I believe **astonishing** would also serve. (adj) Causing astonishment or surprise; amazing